# How to replace backslash with my comma in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a program that will print strings and turn them into a list. My problem is when I print it I get backslashes (`\`) instead of `,` which I can't use. Any help on replacing it?

Here is what I tried:

```
def Convert(string):
    li = list(string.split('\\'))
    return li
```

Full Code:

```
def Convert(string):
    li = list(string.split('\\'))
    return li


str1 = ("""Kellokolme1@gmail.com
stacexbeatz500@gmail.com
hiimjose789@gmail.com
AlexSaberOfficial@gmail.com
ferncuevas15@gmail.com
royodero45@gmail.com
youthdombeats@gmail.com
chris.rhames5@gmail.com
bloombeats01@gmail.com
16premebeats@gmail.com
TmanBeatz.Info@Gmail.com
alexbuus65@gmail.com
Armotunez@gmail.com
aydbeats@gmail.com
iblouir79@hotmail.com
contact@curtbain.com
aminebeats7@gmail.com
markusrovelstad@gmail.com
eddie@lilsoy.com
t-way974@hotmail.com
prodbykamikaze@gmail.com
matteobeats08@gmail.com
markusrovelstad@gmail.com
grandmbeats@gmail.com""")

print(Convert(str1))
```

I would like to see the commas but instead i get this:

```
['Kellokolme1@gmail.com\nstacexbeatz500@gmail.com\nhiimjose789@gmail.com\nAlexSaberOfficial@gmail.com\nferncuevas15@gmail.com\nroyodero45@gmail.com\nyouthdombeats@gmail.com\nchris.rhames5@gmail.com\nbloombeats01@gmail.com\n16premebeats@gmail.com\nTmanBeatz.Info@Gmail.com\nalexbuus65@gmail.com\nArmotunez@gmail.com\naydbeats@gmail.com\niblouir79@hotmail.com\ncontact@curtbain.com\naminebeats7@gmail.com\nmarkusrovelstad@gmail.com\neddie@lilsoy.com\nt-way974@hotmail.com\nprodbykamikaze@gmail.com\nmatteobeats08@gmail.com\nmarkusrovelstad@gmail.com\ngrandmbeats@gmail.com']
```

Comment: (a) `str1` doesn't contain any backslashes. (b) Why are you constructing your string like that in the first place? Is that value coming from somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split on `\n` (newline):

```py
def Convert(string):
    li = list(string.split('\n'))
    return li
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [str.splitlines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) on your string:

```
str1 = """Kellokolme1@gmail.com
stacexbeatz500@gmail.com
hiimjose789@gmail.com
"""

str1.splitlines()
# ['Kellokolme1@gmail.com', 'stacexbeatz500@gmail.com', 'hiimjose789@gmail.com']
```